# How to show products of a WooCommerce shipping class using shortcode?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode, shipping-method

I try to show products of a WooCommerce shipping class in page with help of a shortcode, for example, like this: [free-shipping-products] or something like this.
The shortcode depends on shipping class. or by using ID of shipping class.

How can I do this?

I did not find any plugin for this matter and need to add the shortcode in a page.